# Why does 'this' result as 'Undefined' in method [javascript]

Tags: javascript, object, methods, ecmascript-6, this

I was studying the behavior of this inside object methods and I have got stuck at one output.

Here is the code.

```
'use strict';

let obj, method;

obj = {
  go() { alert(this); }
};

obj.go();               // (1) [object Object]

(obj.go)();             // (2) [object Object]     QUESTION 2

(method = obj.go)();    // (3) undefined

(obj.go || obj.stop)(); // (4) undefined     ------> Doubt  <-------------------
```

So if the fourth one is logically equivalent to the second one, why does the logical **OR** cause the context to be lost?

**Part-2**

*Please correct me if I am wrong.*

1. The evaluation of this ocurrs the way it is called/invoked with function declaration/expression.
2. Inside arrow function, `this` always refers to its enclosing parent . [lexical scope]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 2, the parentheses do not change the fact that the function reference value on the left side of `()` came from an object property reference. Thus the function invocation happens in exactly the same way as in case 1, with the object reference bound to `this`.

In case 4, however, the `||` evaluation inside those parentheses cause that relationship to be lost; all that's left is the function reference without any related object. That's because the logic of `||` doesn't care about the fact that the function reference came from an object property lookup, so it's result value is just the function reference "naked".

As to your follow-on questions, neither assertions are worded correctly. The value of `this` does depend on how a function is invoked, but that has nothing to do with where the function came from or how it was declared. Inside arrow functions, the value of `this` is not a reference to its lexical parent, it's the same as the value of `this` in the lexical parent.

Comment: I will say that this behavior is somewhat surprising, though I think if it worked differently that would introduce a tremendous amount of complexity in the runtime.

Comment: (obj.go || obj.stop)(); -> how the evaluation happens?...first dot operator, then or operator, obj.go is true..thus it reduces to obj.go()...i know somewhere my assertion is wrong..Please elaborate the evaluation process

Comment: The `obj.go` expression is evaluated, and its value is checked to see if it's "truthy".  It is, so the evaluation of the `||` expression stops and the overall value is the function reference. If you read the spec (which is tedious and difficult, unfortunately) the key difference is the difference between getting a *reference* to a value and the actual value itself. It's fairly arcane; it's more practical to simply accept that the relationship between a function-valued object property and the object is lost in any expression evaluation.

Comment: so in any expression evaluation, the reference values gets lost..right?

Comment: @tedd the object - function relationship gets lost, yes, unless the expression is **only** `object.propertyName`

Answer (score 1):

[@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) already answered your question. Just for fun: knowing what you know now, you can get your `obj.go` method to run in its own scope, wrapping in an arrow function expression:

```js
let obj, method, otherMethod, m2;

obj = {
  foo: `obj.foo here, saying: done`,
  go(txt = ``) { console.log(`obj.go here, called as: ${txt} => ${this.foo}`); }
};
(txt => obj.go(txt))(`(txt => obj.go(txt))([...])`);
(method = txt => obj.go(txt))(`(method = txt => obj.go(txt))([...])`);
(obj.go && 
  (txt => obj.go(txt)) || 
  obj.stop)(`(obj.go && txt => obj.go(txt) || obj.stop)([...])`);

// or use a wrapper (factory function)
const wrap = (...[obj, method, txtArg]) => () => obj[method](txtArg);
(otherMethod = wrap(obj, `go`, `(otherMethod = wrap(obj, \`go\`, \`[...]\`))()`))();

// or make `go` a getter and that getter a factory function
let otherObj = {
  foo: `and hithere, here's otherObj.foo`,
  get go() { return txt => 
    console.log( `otherObj.go here, called as: ${txt} => ${this.foo}` ); }
};

(m2 = otherObj.go)(`(m2 = otherObj.go)([...])`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, #'s 3 and 4 return `[object Window]`

See comments:

```js
let obj, method;

obj = {
  go() { alert(this); }
};

obj.go();               // [object Object] represents obj

(obj.go)();             // [object Object] represents obj

(method = obj.go)();    // [object Window] because the go method is not running in the context of obj

(obj.go || obj.stop)(); //  Same as above
```

Comment: i have used the 'use strict ', i have added that  to the code now